# "echo y | rmdir /s dirname": how to suppress "dirname, Are you sure (Y/N)? y"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I run this in batch file postbuild:

```
"echo y | rmdir /s dirname"
```

works fine but echoes the line:

```
dirname, Are you sure (Y/N)? y
```

I would like to get rid of that, cause VS output window shows it.

Is there another command I can use maybe or some trick to suppress it?

Comment: Use the `/q` (quiet) flag so that the confirmation message isn't shown.

Comment: with `/q` flag, you could drop the `echo` part BTW.

Comment: darn... I overlooked that. Thank you all for your answers! I dropped the echo. Someone should answer the question so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a directory without any prompts, you shoud use the `/q` (quiet) option.

`rmdir <directory> /q`

You probably want to remove the entire directory and its files/subdirectories, so you should also add the `/s` (remove tree) option:

`rmdir <directory> /s /q`

`rmdir` shows an error message if the directory does not exist or when there's a file in use inside it. You can hide that messages with:

`rmdir <directory> /s /q 2>NUL`

Hope it helps.